# How long does Launchpad typically take to process bug data?

Tags: launchpad, apport

I started the bug creation process with `apport-cli` and followed the link it gave me.

However it's been processing for several hours now.

[image: Please wait while bug data is processed. This page will refresh every 10 seconds until processing is complete.]

When should I give up waiting and try again?

Comment: It varies greatly on the size of the upload by apport and on how overloaded Launchpad is.  It can take a long time when the server is broken or having issues as well.  Did you refresh your page and see if it actually finished and you're just looking at a cached page?

Comment: @ThomasWard a full page refresh makes no difference

Comment: @ThomasWard what's "a long time"? Hours? Days? Weeks?

Answer (score 0):

After ~20 hours it finally timed out.

> ### Timeout error
>
> Sorry, something just went wrong in Launchpad.
>
> We’ve recorded what happened, and we’ll fix it as soon as possible. Apologies for the inconvenience.
>
> Trying again in a couple of minutes might work.
>
> If you report this as a bug, please include the error ID below, preferably by copying and pasting it rather than by taking a screenshot.

So that puts an upper limit on how long it can take.